# Searching multiple text files for two strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have a folder with many text files (EPA10.txt, EPA55.txt, EPA120.txt..., EPA150.txt). I have 2 strings that are to be searched in each file and the result of the search is written in a text file result.txt. So far I have it working for a single file. Here is the working code:

```
if 'LZY_201_335_R10A01' and 'LZY_201_186_R5U01' in open('C:\\Temp\\lamip\\EPA150.txt').read():
    with open("C:\\Temp\\lamip\\result.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write('Current MW in node is EPA150')
else:
    with open("C:\\Temp\\lamip\\result.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write('NOT EPA150')
```

Now I want this to be repeated for all the text files in the folder. Please help.

Comment: Your `if` condition is wrong, it is always going to be True.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary not always, but only if the second string is in the file

Comment: that's what I want. Only when both the strings are present in the file, then it should return true else false.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Ouch! I misread it.

Comment: @slyclam Your `if` condition is equilvalent to `if ('LZY_201_335_R10A01') and  ('LZY_201_186_R5U01' in open('C:\\Temp\\lamip\\EPA150.txt').read())`. Does that look correct to you?

Comment: No. I got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that you have some amount of files named from `EPA1.txt` to `EPA150.txt`, but you don't know all the names, you can put them all together inside a folder, then read all the files in that folder using the `os.listdir()` method to get a list of filenames. You can read the file names using `listdir("C:/Temp/lamip")`.

Also, your `if` statement is wrong, you should do this instead:

```
text = file.read()
if "string1" in text and "string2" in text
```

Here's the code:

```
from os import listdir

with open("C:/Temp/lamip/result.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in listdir("C:/Temp/lamip"):
        with open('C:/Temp/lamip/' + filename) as currentFile:
            text = currentFile.read()
            if ('LZY_201_335_R10A01' in text) and ('LZY_201_186_R5U01' in text):
                f.write('Current MW in node is ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
            else:
                f.write('NOT ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
```

PS: You can use `/` instead of `\\` in your paths, Python automatically converts them for you.

Comment: The file numberings are not sequential i.e not EPA1. txt.......EPA150.txt.  They are random but the highest is 150. Will this code work still?

Comment: `with open('C:/Temp/lamip/MyFolder/' + filename).read() as currentFile` is still wrong.

Comment: My script is in `C:\Python27\Scripts` and the folder containing the text files is `C:\Temp\lamip`. This folder also has the result.txt file. What modifications should I do?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\lamip.py", line 41, in <module>
    f.writeline('NOT ' + filename[:-4])
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'writeline'

Comment: @slyclam oh I forgot that you can't use writeline, I edited my answer: just use .write and add a \n character at the end

Comment: It is working but only for a single string i.e only if I do this 
`if 'LZY_201_335_R10A01' in currentFile.read():## and 'LZY_201_186_R5U01' in currentFile.read():`

Comment: @slyclam what do you mean?

Comment: Your code is executing without errors. But, I am getting `NOT <filenames>` only. Although the strings are present in one of the files. When I put only one string (for ex: LZY_201_335_R10A01) then I get the desired output. But when I put 2 strings like in your code, then I am getting NOT EPA150.

Comment: @slyclam that's not my error. Does your EPA150 contain **both** strings? Maybe you wanted to check if the text contained **at least** one of them? If so you have to use **or** instead of **and**.

Comment: the EPA150.txt has both the strings. But they are not in same line.

Comment: @slyclam maybe it was because of the .read() method being called two times. I edited the code assigning the text to a temporary variable to check. See if it works...

Answer (score 3):

Modularise! **Modularise!**

Well, not in the terms of having to write distinct Python modules, but isolate the different tasks at hand.

1. Find the files you wish to search.
2. Read the file and locate the text.
3. Write the result into a separate file.

Each of these tasks can be solved independently. I.e. to list the files, you have `os.listdir` which you might want to filter.

For step 2, it does not matter whether you have 1 or 1,000 files to search. The routine is the same. You merely have to iterate over each file found in step 1. This indicates that step 2 could be implemented as a function that takes the filename (and possible search-string) as argument, and returns `True` or `False`.

Step 3 is the combination of each element from step 1 and the result of step 2.

The result:

```
files = [fn for fn in os.listdir('C:/Temp/lamip') if fn.endswith('.txt')]
# perhaps filter `files`

def does_fn_contain_string(filename):
  with open('C:/Temp/lamip/' + filename) as blargh:
    content = blargh.read()
    return 'string1' in content and/or 'string2' in content

with open('results.txt', 'w') as output:
  for fn in files:
    if does_fn_contain_string(fn):
      output.write('Current MW in node is {1}\n'.format(fn[:-4]))
    else:
      output.write('NOT {1}\n'.format(fn[:-4]))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\lamip.py", line 42, in <module>
    if does_fn_contain_string(fn):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\lamip.py", line 37, in does_fn_contain_string
    with open('C:/Temp/lamip/' + filename).read() as content:
AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: Sorry. Thought we could use a ``open(...).read()`` in the context manager (the ``with``-construct). It appears we cannot.

Comment: Please help in solving the problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\lamip.py", line 47, in <module>
    output.write('NOT {1}\n'.format(fn[:-4]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: I'll leave that one for you to debug, as it is an trivial but common error. Hint: it's on the "fn[:-4]" part, so look at which values "fn" is taking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a `for` loop that runs through all your `.txt` files in the current working directory.

```
import os

with open("result.txt", "w") as resultfile:
    for result in [txt for txt in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if txt.endswith(".txt")]:
        if 'LZY_201_335_R10A01' and 'LZY_201_186_R5U01' in open(result).read():
             resultfile.write('Current MW in node is {1}'.format(result[:-4]))
         else:
             resultfile.write('NOT {0}'.format(result[:-4]))
```

Comment: I am getting incorrect syntax. There seems to be an error for the **:** in the for loop end. 

`for result in [txt for txt in os.listdir(os.getwcd()) if txt.endswith(".txt"):`

Comment: @slyclam it was lacking the closing bracket for the list comprehension. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\lamip.py", line 36, in <module>
    for result in [txt for txt in os.listdir(os.getwcd()) if txt.endswith(".txt")]:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getwcd'

Comment: @slyclam Apologies for all the typos, it's supposed to be `os.getcwd()` as in "get current workind directory". Hope it works now. Good luck!

Comment: Nope. Dosen't work. Nothing gets written in the result.txt file. Please help.

Comment: @slyclam, this is getting embarrassing for me, set the `"w"` attribute for the `result.txt` file.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\lamip.py", line 41, in <module>
    resultfile.write('NOT {1}'.format(result[:-4]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @slyclam ... and Python indexes from zero